# Materials Modeling with Raspberry Pi?

Tags: molecular-modeling, quantum-chemistry, high-performance-computing

Does anyone have any knowledge or direction for creating a homemade [Beowolf cluster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beowulf_cluster) for materials modeling?I would like to be able to run my own "hobby" simulations at home, so a low energy, low capital investment is what I seek.

[Raspberry Pi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi) and [ODroid](https://www.hardkernel.com/shop/odroid-mc1-my-cluster-one-with-32-cpu-cores-and-8gb-dram/) use small, cheap, low energy single board computers (SBC) that can be stacked into a cluster. A demonstration cluster was made in 2013 in the UK [Raspberry Pi demonstration cluster](http://www.southampton.ac.uk/%7Esjc/raspberrypi/). I have not found examples of molecular simulation being applied to these clusters (GROMACS or GAMESS type applications). My concern is that they may not be able to handle long term simulations?

**Are there any recent examples of these SBC clusters handling prolonged workload, and in particular, are there examples of molecular simulations being successful?** I have tried reaching out to the SBC community, however, molecular dynamics and quantum chemistry gets me blank stares.

I just found this paper comparing the ODroid-MC1 to supercomputer cluster CPU's. The Odroid-MC1 is a 32 cpu cluster for \$220, and the CPU's compared against retail at \$9000+. The test problem was solving Lattice-Boltzmann flow computations. [They found](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0167739X18322015) that ODroid-MC1 was only 4 times slower, and this was largely due to its use of 32-bit ARMv7. It can therefore likely be expected that using 64-bit ARMv8 and newer would make ODroid-MC1 very competitive, and incredibly cheap. ODroid consistently beats raspberry pi for speed.

Comment: +1. It's interesting. There is no HPC Stack Exchange. I tried inquiring about one in the past, but was immediately shot down. The HPC tag on this site seems to have had a bit of success, even though some of the questions were more about HPC than about the Materials Modeling (for example the question about alternative schedulers to SLURM, and the question about linear algebra libraries for non-Intel CPUs). Let's see what happens. If you want to do calculations for real research though (not just some fun hobby), I don't think anything homemade will compete with the big national clusters.

Comment: Agreed on the competitive status. I am an algorithms guy though, I just need to simulate ~6000 atoms and I can prove if my idea worked or not. While I use supercomputers to run hundreds of jobs trivially in parallel, that is only for production. For testing, I only need to simulate a couple at a time, so even a couple desktops would do the trick really. Gromacs can do 4 ns of a 6000 atom system in a couple hours.

Comment: If you're using supercomputers to run hundreds of jobs, can you not also use those machines to do the 6000-atom testing of your novel algorithms?

Comment: I should say in past-tense I ran hundreds. I am done my PhD now and no longer have the luxury of access to a cluster. My new access is with a new supervisor, and I do not want to chew up this groups resources, with what is my personal work. I also don't want to give a funding agency credit for research they really did not do or truly fund. If they want to be mentioned, they can actually pay me a real amount of funding. My ultimate goal would be to be able to run hundreds of 4 ns simulations on < 20,000 atom systems. I may need to wait a couple years

Comment: I think this is an interesting question and something I have thought from a hobbyist perspective. People once thought that using graphics cards to do calculations was not worth it either (I remember a story of early pioneers in that field using hardware found in playstations!)

Comment: Would it be too much to say which country this is? Many supercomputing centres allow individuals to apply for time on their machines (you would not have to pay any money). Many of these centers do not even require you to be living in the same country as the supercomputing centre. The idea of making a "cluster" with Raspberry Pi or something else at home, is interesting, but practically I would not recommend it for doing any algorithm development or calculations.

Comment: Oh, I am in canada. Good luck doing computing on a default account. Sure it happens... After a 4 day wait. I can run my jobs on a desktop. What I am after though is a cheaper, lower operating cost, than getting several desktops strung together. https://www.hardkernel.com/shop/odroid-mc1-my-cluster-one-with-32-cpu-cores-and-8gb-dram/ provides 32 cores for $220. However, it may not actually work for gromacs/gamess/gaussian/orca/openMM etc. I abhor queue times :)

Comment: @CodyAldaz I have a feeling that in a few years, it will be quite feasible to make a 100 cpu cluster for a couple hundred dollars and be able to perform at least a few nanoseconds per day on each cpu. It would be real swell if it turned out the future was today though.

Comment: As an alternative, have you considered GPUs? Even 1080, 2080.. cards are good for classical MM calculations, and you can have more than one in a desktop.

Comment: @Greg My dream is to convert entirely to writing GPU code and running programs that use GPU. The programs I use can all do GPU, however, I write alot of my own code, and I am not sophisticated enough yet to manage GPU. It is on my list of things to learn. Also, I want to run many jobs trivially in parallel, and cannot afford alot of GPU's. But, if they get done 10 x faster, I can just run the trivial jobs in serial, and get as much, or more, done per day. So, it is something I am looking into

Comment: If you want HPC at home, the best option is still GPU computation. Using OpenCL on a modern AMD graphical card (Nvidia unfortunately push for it own privative and non-compatible CUDA, so OpenCL is only available at version 1.2 -> non-go) gives you a decent amount of MFlops / dollar. For example, my desktop is < 2k$ and bring about 3.5Tflops in double, 14Tflops in single (peak)

Comment: Is your edit perhaps an "answer"?

Comment: Uhm, it could be, I don't naturally think of answering my own question when others have already done so

Comment: Can you put a proper link to the paper, DOI or something? Now it is a link to a university page, which doesn’t allow access anyone who is not at UGuelph.

Comment: @Greg yep, good catch thanks! It should work, but let me know if it does not.

Comment: Why not look around on the cloud market? There are quite a few providers who offer nodes eminently suitable for HPC calculations, together with fast interconnects etc. It would be more expensive in the long run if you had 100% utilisation at home, but if not, the cloud could turn out cheaper.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Raspberry Pi clusters are okay for studying networked systems and job schedulers, but bad for any real calculations. There are several problems: there's very little memory per CPU, the interconnect is slow, having local disk is hard... but worst of all, the bang per buck is very low, see e.g. [a Phoronix benchmark](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=raspberry-pi-burst&num=6).
So, in summary: Intel/AMD is still cheaper for running actual calculations, but a Raspberry Pi cluster is quite cheap to set up so it could serve as a toy / test system.

More powerful ARM workstations that are actually designed for running calculations (many CPUs, large memory, local storage) could be a game changer, but these are still not common.

Edit: I've just benchmarked a Raspberry Pi 4. According to linpack, it's about the same speed as a cheap celeron laptop; however, it's terribly slow in desktop use. Both are at least 10 times less powerful than my work laptop; I'd estimate that the raspberry pis are at least 3-4 times more expensive per gflop than good PCs at the moment.

Comment: Yeah, it seems I have to wait a few years. I will probably go for a desktop instead.

Comment: @CharlieCrown: Seems unlikely to pan out.  If the micro-architectures get cheaper to string together in a huge network, then the folks at Intel/AMD/etc. will just start doing that instead.  CPU manufacturers are going in that direction (e.g., [AMD's Infinity Fabric](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/amd/infinity_fabric)) as well as research into RAM that basically does computations in conjunction with its memory operations ([computational RAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_RAM)).

Comment: @CharlieCrown: That said, you probably want to look for "_compute modules_" rather than stand-alone units.  Sometimes they're meant to go into existing PC's as co-processors (analogous to using a GPU as a co-processor) and sometimes they're basically just stripped-down computers (Raspberry Pi seems to have versions like this).

Comment: @Nat thanks, I will take a look for compute modules. I am open to anything!

Comment: @SusiLehtola: of course, wrong button.

Answer (score 11):

@Susi already provided an excellent answer. I just want to add that for most applications in materials modeling, there is a relatively high overhead for parallelization. Basically, breaking up a problem into smaller and smaller pieces means that you are spending more and more time on communication between the nodes, etc.

Basically, you usually still want individual cores that are pretty fast. If you want to build a cheap hobby cluster yourself, the best option may be to try to get used hardware. A old desktop-class CPU can still be quite useful. Older server-grade stuff could also be really cheap since businesses might essentially be throwing them away.

You could also try to use *diskless nodes*. Finally, the nodes don't need to have full cases, nor do you need proper CPU racks. I know people who have essentially put a [bunch of motherboards on cheap wire racks and hooked them all up.](http://physics.bu.edu/~sandvik/clusters.html)

Comment: To note it, the bunch-of-motherboards-hooked-together thing is sometimes called a [_blade server_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blade_server).

Answer (score 6):

> I would like to be able to run my own "hobby" simulations at home, so a low energy, low capital investment is what I seek.

Disclaimer. I have not made a Raspberry Pi cluster.

A few months ago (10/24/2021) the [Turing Pi 2](https://turingpi.com/turing-pi-v2-is-here/) board was released.

For a YouTube video (12/01/2021) on how to build a computer with 4 [Raspberry Pi compute modules](https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/compute-module-4/?variant=raspberry-pi-cm4001000) see this Jeff Geerling video.

[4 Pis on a mini ITX board! The Turing Pi 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IUPYpZBfsMU)

---

If anyone is wondering if Raspberry Pi is considered a valid way to go then consider this.

[Raspberry Pi supercomputer: Los Alamos to use 10,000 tiny boards to test software](https://www.zdnet.com/article/raspberry-pi-supercomputer-los-alamos-to-use-10000-tiny-boards-to-test-software/)

---

Something to keep an eye on are these:

[Uptime Lab's CM4 Blade adds NVMe, TPM 2.0 to Raspberry Pi](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2021/uptime-labs-cm4-blade-adds-nvme-tpm-20-raspberry-pi)

As noted on the web site

> A 1U rackmount enclosure is in the works, and 16 of these boards would deliver:
>
> 64 ARM CPU cores
> up to 128 GB of RAM
> 16 TB+ of NVMe SSD storage

Jeff has a video on these

[Uptime Lab's CM4 Blade adds NVMe, TPM 2.0 to Raspberry Pi](https://youtu.be/zH9GwYZu_aE)

but AFAIK these blades are not yet for sale. (12/09/2021) :-(

Comment: Of interest: [Arm-Based 128-Core Ampere CPUs Cost a Fraction of x86 Price](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/ampere-altra-max-128-core-priced)

Comment: Of interest: [Raspberry Pi Locator](https://rpilocator.com/)