# How to analyze the space group of a relaxed structure that has fractional site occupancies

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, crystal-structure, space-groups

I am using VASP package to model a material that has fractional site occupancies. An appropriate supercell (cif) was generated using `supercell` package and converted to `POSCAR` using VESTA. Then the structural relaxation was performed. Now I have the relaxed structure (`CONTCAR`) and I want to analyze its space group.

I tried `pymatgen`, but it doesn't seem to be working for fractional site occupant materials, because the original `POSCAR` structure is `Pm-3m`, however is identified as `P4/mmm` by pymatgen.

Is there any other tool I can use to analyze such structures?

Comment: I was desperately looking for materials modelling Q&A site and finally here we are. Hope it will help a lot!

Comment: I'm very happy that you found us. I've been trying to recruit people since [9 months ago](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958?phase=commitment&committers=totalreputation#tab-top) and it would have been nice if I managed to reach you back then. I also tried to make a site like this (though different) in 2018, but StackExchange rejected the proposal. How did you find us? Which Hot-Network-Question? We are only 1 month old so this is the best time to get involved!

Comment: I was actually on StackExchange Chemistry and saw a hot-network-question (I don't exactly remember). Always reluctant to ask materials questions on chemistry site. I hope this site will attract many experts too.

Comment: Was it [this one](https://materials.stackexchange.com/q/1224/5), or something else?

Comment: I definitely recall this question. Probably it was the one I saw.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### ASE

The [ASE](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/index.html) python package can find the space group of a structure using the [`get_spacegroup`](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/_modules/ase/spacegroup/spacegroup.html#get_spacegroup) function as follows.

```py
import ase.io as io
from ase.spacegroup import get_spacegroup

structure = io.read('path/to/POSCAR')
sp = get_spacegroup(structure,symprec=1e-5)
print(sp)
```

I am not sure as to whether it can deal with fractional occupancies, but it seems it can from the [source of the Spacegroup class](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/_modules/ase/spacegroup/spacegroup.html#Spacegroup).

Comment: Thanks. This module can deal with fractional site occupancies (handling cif, POSCAR etc,, whereas pymatgen just gives an error). However, I had to do a small workaround to get the space group.

Comment: @AchinthaIhalage It would be helpful for future visitors if you could edit the workaround into the answer and I can accept the edit. Or ofcourse you can write another answer :).

Comment: It was nothing major. I was focused on one fractional site occupant material. It's space group was correctly identified by ASE using the cif file as it is, I guess it will work for other materials too. But when I created a supercell POSCAR, the identified space group was wrong, so I had to convert it back to cif to get the correct space group. And I'm not sure if this dirty workaround works for other materials.

Answer (score 9):

#### spg-lib

Another light-weight option is the spg-lib by Atsushi Togo and Isao Tanaka described [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.01590) with multiple interfaces that can be found [here](https://spglib.github.io/spglib/index.html).

Especially, the tolerance parameters for the detection of symmetries are quite handy.

Answer (score 5):

#### Bilbao Crystallographic Server

You can take a look at the [Bilbao Crystallographic Server](https://www.cryst.ehu.es/wiki/index.php/About_the_Bilbao_Crystallographic_Server).

It has several tools for symmetry and structure analysis in the Solid State Theory Applications section.

Answer (score 3):

#### FINDSYM

Another useful tool to determine crystal symmetry is [FINDSYM](https://stokes.byu.edu/iso/findsym.php). It works with the .cif format exclusively, so you may have to convert your structural files to .cif before using it.